# Converting ICON to BITMAP -- side-effect

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, gdi

How do I make it so that this code strictly does the conversion from a Windows ICON to a CBitmap?

The code is incorrectly displaying the new bitmap on screen.  :(

This code was acquired from 'someone' on the web.  And though it achieves it's goal of converting the ICON, **it also displays the icon on screen (upper left hand corner) which it should not be doing.**

**D'oh!**

```
void CUIHelper::ConvertIconToBitmap2(CBitmap& bmpObj, HICON hIcon) 
{
    CClientDC clientDC(NULL);
    CDC memDC;
    memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(&clientDC);

    ASSERT(hIcon);
    ICONINFO info;
    VERIFY(GetIconInfo(hIcon, &info));

    BITMAP bmp;
    GetObject(info.hbmColor, sizeof(bmp), &bmp);

    HBITMAP hBitmap = (HBITMAP)CopyImage(info.hbmColor, IMAGE_BITMAP, 0, 0, 0);
    ASSERT(hBitmap);
    ASSERT(memDC.GetSafeHdc());

    HBITMAP hOldBmp = (HBITMAP)memDC.SelectObject(hBitmap);
    clientDC.BitBlt(0, 0, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, &memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    memDC.SelectObject(hOldBmp);

    VERIFY( bmpObj.Attach(hBitmap) );

    DeleteObject(info.hbmColor);
    DeleteObject(info.hbmMask);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am dumb when it comes to GDI.

`clientDC.BitBlt(0, 0, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, &memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);`

should be

`memDC.BitBlt(0, 0, bmp.bmWidth, bmp.bmHeight, &memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);`